# Payara (glassfish) Administration Console stuck at loading

Tags: java, glassfish, payara, microprofile, jakarta-ee

I am trying to access Payara Administration Console at `http://localhost:4848/` but upon opening the link the window never goes beyond the screen saying `The Admin Console is starting. Please wait`. It keeps loading and loading. I have tried it on multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome etc) but it didn't work. I also tried `enable-secure-admin` but no effect. However, I can successfully deploy my application war and can also access it. Below are the logs that I get when I try to access Admin Console (there are some expire SSL certs logs that I have omitted):

```
[2019-08-26T13:25:05.999+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818705999] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java security manager is disabled.]]

[2019-08-26T13:25:06.000+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818706000] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Entering Security Startup Service.]]

[2019-08-26T13:25:06.013+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818706013] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

[2019-08-26T13:25:06.401+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818706401] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application __admingui done in 2,770 ms]]

[2019-08-26T13:25:07.230+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818707230] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.payara-p2 for context '']]

[2019-08-26T13:25:08.119+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=169 _ThreadName=Thread-26] [timeMillis: 1566818708119] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [__admingui] at [/]]]

[2019-08-26T13:25:08.900+0200] [Payara 5.192] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=170 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1566818708900] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]
```

I am on Mac, java version is `1.8.0_161`. 
Payara version: `Payara Server 5.192 #badassfish (build 115)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue is resolved somehow.

`http://localhost:4848` still shows that main login page and stuck at `The Admin Console is starting. Please wait.`

However, I tried `localhost:4848/login.jsf` and patiently waited for like 30 seconds and a login screen popped-up. I entered my credentials there and then I was able to log in. I am still not sure though why the main URL is not working.

It works on Chrome as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and wasted 2 days for investigation and search.

And finally solved by clearing cookies of browser.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, cannot comment due to low rep.)

Did you try the **https** URL after enabling `secure-admin`?
Where did you install payara / your domain? We once had problems with a symbolic link or directory that contained special characters.

Edit: disabling Adblocker worked for me.

Comment: I download the zipped file from this link (https://www.payara.fish/software/downloads/). Yes, https didn't work either. I am directly using the unzipped folder (no symlinks).

Comment: Funny, just tried it on Firefox on Ubuntu and it did not work also (usually use asadmin command line options). Disabled Adblock Plus and it worked. ABP reported that 2 items were blocked.

Comment: That's strange behavior. I am able to log in though if interested check the answer.

Comment: Re answer: are you maybe in a restricted network environment? Sounds like some sort of network timeout.

Comment: yeah I get these logs
https://pastebin.com/raw/eAyaBjmi
some timeout, but I am unable to comprehend why? Do you have any clue?

Comment: Are you now using http or https? You said that you enabled secure admin.

Comment: Yeah not using secure admin anymore. I downloaded fresh zip and working on it.